# Efficient evaluation of arbitrary functions given as data, in C++

Tags: c++, optimization, mathematical-optimization

Consider the following goal:

Create a program that solves: `minimize f(x)` for an arbitrary `f` and `x` supplied as input.

How could one design a C++ program that could receive a description of `f` and `x` and process it efficiently?

If the program was actually a C++ library then one could explicitly write the code for `f` and `x` (probably inheriting from some base function class for `f` and state class for `x`). 
However, what should one do if the program is for example a service, and the user is sending the description of `f` and `x` in some high level representation, e.g. a JSON object?

Ideas that come to mind
1- Convert `f` into an internal function representation (e.g. a list of basic operations). Apply those whenever `f` is evaluated.
Problems: inefficient unless each operation is a batch operation (e.g. if we are doing vector or matrix operations with large vectors / matrices).

2- Somehow generate C++ code and compile the code for representing `x` and computing `f`. Is there a way to restrict compilation so that only that code needs to be compiled, but the rest of the code is 'pre-compiled' already?

Comment: Use an embeddable JIT-compiler, like luajit?

Comment: How they do it, I have no clue, but it is done in the C++ version of the Acado toolkit. http://acado.github.io/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual approach used by the [mp library](https://github.com/ampl/mp) and others is to create an expression tree (or DAG) and use some kind of a [nonlinear optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonlinear_programming) method that normally relies on derivative information which can be computed using automatic or numeric differentiation.

An expression tree can be efficiently traversed for evaluation using a [generic visitor](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/05/17/the-curiously-recurring-template-pattern-in-c) pattern. Using JIT might be an overkill unless the time taken for evaluating a function takes substantial fraction of the optimization time.